# 1970s (?) young adult book about a race of noncorporeal aliens on Earth

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, young-adult

A race of aliens from a planet so technologically advanced that they evolved beyond the use of bodies. They floated through space until they arrived on Earth. They enter a human's blood stream through a rabbit bite and telekinetically destroy all forms of technology around any human they infect. I think the first object was a jukebox.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall any details of the cover?  Was this an alien invasion novel, or just a story of incompatible types?

Comment: I don't remember the cover. I think it may have been stars. I don't think it was an invasion story; the aliens think they are saving us from ourselves. At least that is how I remember it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Power Of Stars by Louise Lawrence. They infect a girl called Jane. They are against technology, as this is what caused their planet to destruct; so they blow the jukebox up. Later they destroy Jane's grandmother's washing machine, and she dies. Jane goes to live with a woman (a scientist I believe) who's dog was also infected. The creatures enable Jane to appreciate music etc more. Two boys are friendly with Jane, and at the end of the book she bites one, and we're led to believe she infects him too.

Comment: YES! Thank you, sueelleker.